# A newbie question on cairngorm

Tags: apache-flex, flex3, ria, cairngorm

I am very new to Flex (started learning a couple of days back), I now have some understanding on how to create user interfaces with Flex and how to do MVC with **Cairngorm** and I really started liking it. But I am still lost with changing views using Cairngorm or entirely in Flex. Being a Java/J2EE developer for more than 10 years, it helps me understanding new technologies comparing it with Java. Typically in java world or in any MVC framework, the controller once got the updated modal it redirects or sets the new view to the user. Lets say once I added a new movie to movie database, I want to show the user a view Movie screen and when he deletes a movie I want to take user to list of all movies. The example which I have seen so far(including the diagram explorer) are just changing the modal values and the data is updating in the same view (using `[Bindable]`), but my question is how to change the view depending on the `result` or if it's a `fault` I want to take user to a different screen. How to do that in flex and in Cairngorm. Are there any best practices available and somebody please point me to right direction/resource. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The usual way to do this with Cairngorm is to put the data about the state of the application (eg. the screen the user is on) in the model too. You can, for example, use the `ViewStack` as the main container of the different parts of your application and bind it's `selectedIndex` to a variable in the model which will be used to control the screen that is displayed to the user. Putting it shortly - the state of the application is a reflection of the model.

Answer (score 0):

You may also want to take a look at the [Mate framework](http://mate.asfusion.com/). We recently switched to Mate after using Cairngorm because we found it was a much easier framework to use and understand.

For your example, you would have a `faultHandler` event listener that would call whatever method you wanted in your model. You could easily use that to show or hide whatever you needed to.